# bash script starting multiple process problem

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that process a sequence job like:

compile project A

start program A

compile project B

then start program B

it works fine ,but the problem is when I run the script it compile A works fine then start program A is fine too ,then stopped, when I close program A then program B starts .. how to run them in the same time?

Answer (score 4):

If you put an '&' at the end of the line where you start program A, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm not totally sure which activities you want to run concurrently, but you can put programs in the *background* using the `&` operator:

```
program_a &
```